# clearinterval not caught

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which is being called by an interval.
Then I set an interval the call the function.
I have a mouseleave / mouseenter event to clear and set the interval respectively. But the clearInterval doesn't work, but the anonymous function inside is being called however:

```
interval = setInterval(function() { changeBackground(bgs); }, 2000);


    $('section#main').mouseleave(function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
        alert("j");
    });

    $('section#main').mouseenter(function() {
        var interval = setInterval(function() { changeBackground(bgs); }, 2000);
        alert("n");
    });

    function changeBackground(bgs) {
        $('#black').fadeIn(400, 'swing', function () {
            var Url = "url('content/slides/" + bgs[currentBg] + "')";
            $('#container').css('background-image', Url);
        });

        $('#black').fadeOut();

        currentBg++;

        if(currentBg == totalBg) {
            currentBg = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `interval` is local to the event handler where you declare it. You have to declare the variable in a scope which is visible to both event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var interval = null;

$('section#main').mouseleave(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    alert("j");
});

$('section#main').mouseenter(function() {
    interval = setInterval(function() { changeBackground(bgs); }, 2000);
    alert("n");
});
```

You were var'ing `interval` inside `mouseenter` so it was undefined inside `mouseleave`.

**Edit**

You code amended:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() { changeBackground(bgs); }, 2000);

$('section#main').mouseleave(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    alert("j");
});

$('section#main').mouseenter(function() {
    interval = setInterval(function() { changeBackground(bgs); }, 2000);
    alert("n");
});

function changeBackground(bgs) {
    $('#black').fadeIn(400, 'swing', function () {
        var Url = "url('content/slides/" + bgs[currentBg] + "')";
        $('#container').css('background-image', Url);
    });

    $('#black').fadeOut();

    currentBg++;

    if(currentBg == totalBg) {
        currentBg = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that the interval was initially set in  (which I believe is) the right scope.

Comment: The `interval` in the global scope won't be the same as inside `mouseenter` if you `var` it in there. You need to move `var` to the global `interval` defintion.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Are you sure `changeBackground()` is doing what it is supposed to?

Comment: Yes, it's fully working. I've tried without the initial setInterval, and just create a var interval = "", and then the mouseenter/leave is working.

Comment: You should probably declare your global `interval` as `null` or `""` and only change it on `mouseenter()`. If this still doesn't work then it might be worth putting a jsfiddle up.